# haproxy queue time (qtime) during SSL SNI expection

Tags: performance, ssl, load-balancing, haproxy, sni

We are using **haproxy 1.5.14** as a load-balancer for HTTP as well as HTTPS endpoints for multiple domain hostnames. For the HTTPS endpoints we are using SSL NI headers inspection to find out proper backend node.

In my current installation where multiple https endpoints exist, I've noticed that backend **qtime** stat vaue is pretty high (200-300ms), which disturbs me a lot. **qcur** (current queue lengh) is zero at the same time.
Are we basically slowing down all our requests by 200ms-300ms at haproxy side? (not sure if I understood this value of qtime properly) If yes - I am definitely searching the way to optimize it.

This behavior is only observed on the HTTPS backends and not on HTTP backends. I am wondering if this is result of the frontend SNI headers inspection which are used to determine proper backend nodes. Will request stay in the queue during SSL SNI inspection?

Our current config(for HTTPS endpoints only):

```
global
      log         127.0.0.1 local2
      chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
      pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
      maxconn     40000
      ulimit-n    100000
      user        haproxy
      group       haproxy
      daemon
      stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
      mode                    http
      log                     global
      option                  httplog
      option                  dontlognull
      option http-server-close
      retries                 3
      timeout http-request    1s
      timeout queue           1m
      timeout connect         3s
      timeout client          1m
      timeout server          30s
      timeout http-keep-alive 2s
      timeout check           3s
      maxconn                 40000

frontend https-in *:443
    mode tcp
            option tcplog
            option socket-stats

            tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
            tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }

            use_backend foo-ssl if { req_ssl_sni -m beg foo }
            use_backend bar-ssl if { req_ssl_sni -m beg bar }

backend foo-ssl *:443
    balance leastconn
    mode tcp
            option ssl-hello-chk

            server foo1 x.x.x.x:443 maxconn 10000 check
            server foo2 x.x.x.x:443 maxconn 10000 check

backend bar-ssl *:443
    balance leastconn
    mode tcp
            option ssl-hello-chk

            server bar1 x.x.x.x:443 maxconn 10000 check
            server bar2 x.x.x.x:443 maxconn 10000 check
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen, or it means that your client takes that long to send the SSL hello with the SNI, which is not much expected either. You should take a network capture (tcpdump), and run strace -tt over the haproxy process to know where the time is lost.